# Mirror vector with two distinct values

Tags: r, vector, reverse, flip, mirror

for a regression a "flipped" some dichotomous variables in one data set and want to bring them back into another, similar dataset, matched on the rownames.
So far that is working great, but by matching on the original variables I naturally undo the flipping I did before.

My question basically is: If I have a dichotomous vector, is there a short way to just make a mirrored object of it, like:

```
vector.1 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2)
vector.2 <- c(2,2,2,1,1,2,1)
```

(e.g. `mirror_vector(vector.1)`)

As I understood it, `rev()` changes the order from front to end.

Comment: `3 - vector.1`?

Comment: Hi GordonHL1, Have you looked at using `fcase()` from data.table or `case_when()` from dplyr?

Comment: It is perfect!!! Much thanks!                                                                                       b$Q13_1
b$Q13_1x                                                                                                         b <- b %>% mutate(
  Q13_1x = case_when(
    Q13_1 == 1 ~ 0,
    Q13_1 == 0 ~ 1)
)